# Can I set twitter header using getJSON method?

Tags: jquery, header, twitter, getjson

I am using twitter api for accessing `user_timeline` . I am using `$.getJSON` for that.

```
var url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name='+username;
                var html = "<div class='feeds'>";
                $.getJSON ( url, function( data ){
                    for ( var i in data ){
                        html += "<div class='feed'>" + data[i].text + "</div>";
                    }

                    html += "</div>";
                    $('div.tfeed h2').replaceWith ( html );
                });
```

After few requests I start getting the error `Rate limit exceeded. Clients may not make more than 150 requests per hour.` . Later on I got to know that if I use OAuth then this limit will be increased to slightly higher level(correct me if I am wrong), and this OAuth can be passed in header. I have consumer-key, consumer-secret, access-token, access-token-secret. But how do I pass these?

Do I need to use $.ajax method instead of $.getJSON ? $.ajax have a setting `beforeSend` . But no idea how to use it.

So,

1. Can I use `getJSON` for this requirement ?
2. If no, then will `$.ajax` work? How?
3. And the important thing should I really use my consumer-key, secret, access-token in javascript. I mean I may be wrong, but any one can do a `view-source` of my page and will quickly get this information.

Answer (score 2):

`$.getJSON` is just shorthand for `$.ajax` with dataType: 'json'.

I would create a new service on the serverside that uses your secret stuff, and let it recieve  the not so secret variables with the ajaxcall that youre using now -> let it return the response as JSON. Hope you get the idea, otherwise ill elaborate.

c# sample of how to use the "secret" variables using their c# api

```
OAuthTokens accessToken = new OAuthTokens();
accessToken.ConsumerKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
accessToken.ConsumerSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
accessToken.AccessToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
accessToken.AccessTokenSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
```

Are you using ASP.NET or PHP?

Comment: As of now, nothing in server side. It is plain HTML + jQuery. But if required I will be using j2ee